Ubuntu Server 24.04 - Suddenly no Network Interface working
I hope someone can help me becaus I have no idea.
This evening my ubuntu server 24.04 (installed a few weeks ago and running without any problem) stopped the network connection.
I do not get any ip-adresse nor is the static ip working.
networkctl shows eto1 is off
if I try to set this connection on with ip link eto1 set on
I get
eto1 degraded
but I do not know why degraded and what this really means
I've done

disablend ufw
tried to change the ip-addresse to dhcp (netplan is installed)
moved the hdd to an other desktop, same model
changed network cable an switch-slot
connected an usb-network-card. it was installed, but same behaviour (off and after setting it on  and got degraded)
started with the ubuntu-server-iso on an usb-stick - network connection establshed and working

ifconfig is not working/installed
so i guess something is wrong or happend with the linux-system in the night, maybe after a scheduled reboot but i have no idea what or how to troubelshoot
does someone have any hint for me?
thank you in advance
best regards,
mrmister247
